# How to filter out repeating values in columns (per row)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I substitute particular values by `np.nan` in dataframe using the following condition: if the value of a column is repeated in any subsequent column, than **its first appearance** should be substituted by `np.nan`.

For example,

```
VD_1    VD_2    VD_3     VD_4
Test    Sun     Test     None
Sun     Sun     Fun      Fun
Big     Sand    Fun      Big
```

The result would be this one:

```
VD _1   VD_2    VD_3   VD_4
None    Sun     Test   None
None    Sun     None   Fun
None    Sand    Fun    Big
```

Should I use `drop_duplicates` and `keep` equal to `last`?

Comment: So it may have less columns? You may need a new DataFrame, not `substituting` the values.

Comment: @XinHuang: yes, or it might be the same number of columns with None. See my update.

Comment: @XinHuang: Please see my update. I slightly simplified it.

Comment: Cool. What if a value appear more than twice? Do you keep the second one or last one?

Comment: @XinHuang: In this case I always want to keep the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

- [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) string `None` to `NaN` if necessary
- `apply` [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html)
- [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) column names

---

```
df = df.replace({'None':np.nan})
      .apply(lambda x:x.drop_duplicates(keep='last'), axis=1)
      .reindex(columns=df.columns)

print (df)
   VD_1  VD_2  VD_3 VD_4
0   NaN   Sun  Test  NaN
1   NaN   Sun   NaN  Fun
2   NaN  Sand   Fun  Big
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the same number of columns and just put None instead of first duplicates, keeping always the last unique value?

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First transpose the data frame and use [drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). This one has the option to keep last value. This has to be done for each column and then finally concatenate the outputs together.

```
df_t= df_item.T
clone= df_t[0].drop_duplicates(keep='last').tolist()
cltwo= df_t[1].drop_duplicates(keep='last').tolist()
cl3= df_t[2].drop_duplicates(keep='last').tolist()

print   pd.DataFrame([clone,cltwo,cl3])
```

output

```
  0     1     2
0   Sun  Test  None
1   Sun   Fun  None
2  Sand   Fun   Big
```

Comment: Nice. May the final solution have the same number of columns as the initial data frame?

Comment: aha I see you changed the expected output :). will check that if this is possible

Comment: Also, is it possible to use `lambda` in order to avoid `clone`, `cltwo`, etc. What if I have 100 columns?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will to the trick:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: [x.values[i] if x.values[i] not in x.values[i+1:] else np.nan for i in range(len(x))], axis=1)
```